# Cognos v11 Analytics - Creating data sources

Tags: datasource, cognos-11

Anyone can tell me how to create data source with Cognos Analytics v11 like we used to do with Cognos Administration in previous versions like 10 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are particularly wedded to using the old UI, go into the administration console, where the old UI exists.

You can also set up data source connections in the manage/data server UI in the new UI.

If you have data source connections from 10.2.2 and you want to use them in CA 11 you can do this by going into the administration console and clicking on set properties for the connection.  In the connections tab there is a check box called Allow web-based modeling.  If you check it on the old existing connection will show up in the new ui.  If you want to use the connection in a module you need to load the schemas which you need to use.